# Minimization problem (Snell's law)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

A minimization problem (2C-10) in this [document](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-2-applications-of-differentiation/part-b-optimization-related-rates-and-newtons-method/problem-set-4/MIT18_01SC_pset2prb.pdf) requires showing that sin(a)/sin(b)=ratio of speeds.

The [solution](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-2-applications-of-differentiation/part-b-optimization-related-rates-and-newtons-method/problem-set-4/MIT18_01SC_pset2sol.pdf) (2C-10) shows $T'=\frac {1}{5}*w_1-\frac {1}{3}*w_2$ where $w_1$ is $\dfrac {x}{\sqrt{(100^2+x^2)}}$ which is adjacent/hypo with respect to alpha which is supposed to be cosine not sine (similarly for $w_2$).

Since we're minimizing $T$, we find $T'=0$ which evaluates to
$$
\frac{x}{5\sqrt{100^2+x^2}}-\frac{-x+a}{2\sqrt{100^2+\left(a-x\right)^2}}=0
$$

but $\frac{x}{\sqrt{100^2+x^2}}$ is $\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$ which in the problem represents the $\cos(\alpha)$ not sine.

I guess my question is what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Try reading your question again. It is not at all obvious what you are asking.

Comment: The problem is wrong. Suppose that the swim part is very, very slow compared to the running part. Then you would want to run as much as possible on the beach, then go straight from $Q$ to $B$, which would make $\beta=90^\circ$. But, following the problem, you get $\beta=0$. If you look up Snell's law, you see that the angles are measured from the normal.

Comment: @Andrei You're absolutely right, if I draw the normal and assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are measured from it, it fits.